# Eclipse - Different syntax highlighting for different file extensions

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

I am using the [Eclipse Color Theme](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/) plugin and would like to know if there is a way to associate specific color themes to groups of file extensions.

This is different than the default behavior which applies the current theme to all file extensions.